# AWS Bucket Policy permissions to Load Balancer denied

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-elb, aws-policies

So far my S3 Bucket policy looks like this which I have got from the Generator Policy, I included my Account ID as the Principle to generate the policy but when I go to add this within my Load Balancer attributes it says that "Access Denied for bucket: bucket2. Please check S3bucket permission" What is denying access and how could I fix it?

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "Policy1630018580759",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1630018536294",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::615298492481:root"
            },
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::elb-bkt/logs/AWSLogs/615298492481/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR**

**Replace *elb-account-id* in "Principal" with appropriate region ID from the below list:**

========================================================
[image]

========================================================

The policy mentioned in the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/enable-access-logging.html#attach-bucket-policy) looks something like this:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::elb-account-id:root"
      },
      "Action": "s3:PutObject",
      "Resource": "my-s3-arn"
    }
  ]
}
```

Here we need to update two things - ***elb-account-id*** and ***my-s3-arn***.

The common pitfall we all get into is that **we insert the AWS account ID in place of the *elb-account-id*.** This is what you did here. Replace the AWS account ID with the region ID and it should work.